# How to prevent Prettier from breaking lines with comments?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, prettier

For some reason Prettier breaks the line with comments moving everything after opened braсket on new line.
Here is before
[image: Before auto format]

And here is after
[image: After]

As you can see it makes kind of random formatting: at the 1st line it moves comments to a line above, then it breaks line by brackets, then again moves comments above.
I found here [How to prevent Prettier from moving comments to new line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70841874/how-to-prevent-prettier-from-moving-comments-to-new-line) it's like impossible to prevent Prettier from moving comments to a new line, but I can't find something about how to prevent it from breaking lines and making that bunches of cascades.
Increasing Print width (line limit) does nothing, it's 160 for me now.
Any solutions?

Comment: Three solutions I can think of: 1) stop using reformatting tools that don't improve your code, and 2) write shorter comments. (I don't read whichever language is written in Cyrillic here, but I imagine some of the comments probably aren't necessary at all.  3) Write the comments above the lines they document, rather than using in-line comments.

Comment: @chepner 1) Can't say Prettier doesn't make my code better (sometimes in help to make it better), but sometimes that happens. You don't use any auto formatting tools at all (for example, for Python), do you? 2) You're right, that particular comments are just kind of summary (for learning) 3) I thought about it and try... and it works, just thought maybe there are some solutions for inline comments. Anyway, thanks

Comment: Prettier is used to format front-end web related languages and it's rarely used to format Python code. Maybe you should try [black](https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), a Python code formatter

Comment: @AnsonH thanks, never heard about it! To disable it for Python (cause I use front-end also) I should use .prettierignore file in a folder with .py files or?

Comment: Personally I write comments before I call any function. It makes me read the comment first, knowing what the function should do or what arguments it takes, and then is the proper function call or definition.

Comment: @OM26R No, I don't use formatters, precisely because it's far easier to just write well-formatted code in the first place than to find and deal with corner cases that the formatter gets wrong.

Comment: @OM26R Are you only working on Python code in the current workspace, or your workspace has a mix of front-end code and Python?

Comment: @AnsonH It's a mix, and sometimes even using other languages (PHP, C++), so I can't jump to JetBrains, for example

Comment: @chepner ok, what languages do you write on?

Comment: @whiskeyo thanks, I think it's one of the best solutions )))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@prettier/plugin-python` was deprecated. Use Python formatter instead, for example [Black](https://github.com/psf/black)